# How to use dispatch inside onStompErrorCallback of @stomp/stomp-js library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

My goal is to not duplicate `onStompErrorCallback` callback.

ps: I am working on another solution, I think it would work.

#### TL:DR

The current solution is to write `onStopErrorCallback` directly in React Hook.

```
function LoginScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onStopErrorCallback = (receipt: IFrame) => {
    dispatch(doSomething());   
  }
}
```

However this poses problem, because there are 2 scenarios:

1. When a user login, e.g in a component called `LoginScreen` there is a method called `login`. The `login`'s method do 2 things:

   1. Send POST request to an API and get a token as response.
   2. Do the `WebSocket handshake`, and then `StompCommand.CONNECT`, `StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE`.

   If the user press the `login button`, it will invoke the method.
2. When a user open the app:

   1. The `App` component will send a GET request to authenticate the token. If the token is not expired, it will do the `WebSocket handshake`, and then `StompCommand.CONNECT`, and `StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE`.

The problem is:

1. Each scenario needs access to the `onStompErrorCallback`, and I can't put it anywhere without duplicating the code `increase code smell` since it depends `dispatch(doSomething())`.

What I've tried:

1. I tried to store `new Client(stompConfig: StompConfig)` to redux.

   Redux can't store `onStopErrorCallback: () => void`, or the `new Client(stompConfig: StompConfig)`. It will throw an error.
2. I tried to use custom hook, e.g `useStompClient(X_Auth_Token: string)`.

   Each time a component or screen call `useStompClient(X_Auth_Token: string)`, it creates new `stompClient` instead of using the existing `stompClient`.
3. I tried to use a thunk to the `onStompErrorCallback`

   The `stompClient` can't connect / subscribe / send message.

   ```
   const onStompErrorCallback = (receipt: IFrame): AppThunk => dispatch => {
     dispatch(doSomething());
   }
   ```

#### Edit

This is the best I can do with custom hook. This is not a solution, the `useStompClient` see stompClient as null although it's not, and then it's re-render (this time it see stompClient as not null).

```
let stompClient: Client | null = null;

function useStompClient(X_Auth_Token: string) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  if (stompClient === null && X_Auth_Token !== '') {
    const onConnectCallback = () => {
      console.log('STOMP: connecting');
      stompClient?.subscribe('/user/queue/messages', (message) => {
        const payload = JSON.parse(message.body);
        console.log(payload);
      });
    };

    const onStompErrorCallback = (receipt: IFrame) => {
      if (receipt.headers.message.endsWith('Access is denied')) {
        stompClient?.deactivate();
        dispatch(eraseCredentials());
      }
    };

    const stompConfig: StompConfig = {
      brokerURL: `${environment.wsBaseURL}/chat`,
      forceBinaryWSFrames: true,
      appendMissingNULLonIncoming: true,
      connectHeaders: {
        'X-Auth-Token': X_Auth_Token,
      },
      onConnect: onConnectCallback,
      onStompError: onStompErrorCallback,
    };

    stompClient = new Client(stompConfig);
  }

  return stompClient;
}

export default useStompClient;
```

The solution? Create a 2nd Layer authentication:

1. App
2. AuthenticationLayer
3. WebSocketLayer

Ta Da! Either login and open the app scenario, it would work as expected.

Comment: Can you share the stompClient generation ? Why not declare a stompClient outside of the function and use this in the custom hook? So only one is created per website

Comment: @Domino987 I tried to put the stompClient outside the custom hook, it would not work because changing stompClient will not re-render react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution? Create a 2nd Layer authentication:

1. App: This is where the `Redux` and `NavigationContainer` lives.
2. AuthenticationLayer: This is where the `Stack.Navigator` lives, e.g

```
return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    authenticated ? <Stack.Screen component={LoginScreen} /> : <Stack.Screen component={HomeScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
)
```

3. WebSocketLayer

```
The WebSocketLayer requirements:
1. The `authenticated` is set to true, meaning the app already have the token and ready to be used.
2. Create the `onStompErrorCallback`, etc.
3. Put the stompClient and create a custom setters somewhere outside the React function.
4. Use React.useEffect() to set the stompClient.
```

Ta Da! Either login and open the app scenario, it would work as expected.