# How to persist a variable outside React function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

My goal is to avoid invoking a method because of `React.useEffect` on each re-render. This happens because React thinks the `stompClient` variable is undefined on each re-render.

This is the current solution I use but this will cause the `stompClient` to reconnect on each re-render.

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import {stompClient, setStompClient} from "./services/StompClient";

const AuthenticatedContainer = () => {
  ...

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (stompClient?.connected === undefined || stompClient.connected === false) {
      // this always happens on each re-render, causing unnecessary re-connection.
      setStompClient( the config );
    }
  });

  ....
}
```

./services/StompClient/index.tsx

```
import {Client, IFrame, StompConfig} from '@stomp/stompjs';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

export let stompClient: Client | null = null;

export const setStompClient = (
  onConnect: () => void,
  onStompError: (receipt: IFrame) => void,
) => {
  const stompConfig: StompConfig = {
    brokerURL: `${environment.wsBaseURL}/chat`,
    forceBinaryWSFrames: true,
    appendMissingNULLonIncoming: true,
    onConnect,
    onStompError,
  };

  stompClient = new Client(stompConfig);
};
```

What I've tried:

1. I tried to store the `StompClient` object with redux. It turns out, redux does not like to store non-serializable object. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325195/should-i-store-function-references-in-redux-store#:%7E:text=No%2C%20you%20should%20not%20store,of%20hotkeys%20to%20their%20actionCreatorFuncNames.)
2. I tried to create a custom hook, this would create multiple `StompClient` instead of one. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050308/how-to-use-dispatch-inside-onstomperrorcallback-of-stomp-stomp-js-library?noredirect=1#comment116779456_66050308)

What I've not tried:

1. Use React.Context, I am assuming React.Context and Redux is the same, it does not like storing non serializable object. Please feel free to let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Your `useEffect()` wouldn't run on each render if you properly specified its [dependencies list](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)